# Altering CSV Rows in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I've tried to use the 'Alter Rows' function within a Data Flow in Azure Data Factory to remove rows that match a condition from a CSV dataset.

The Data Preview shows that the rows matched will be deleted, however in the next step 'sink' it seems to ignore that and writes the original rows to the CSV file output.

Is it not possible to use alter rows on a CSV dataset and if not, is there a work around?

Comment: What type of sink dataset are you writing to? Alter Row can only work with target data stores that support CRUD operations: SQL, CosmosDB, Delta Lake.

Comment: I see, what I really want to do is just merge some CSVs together and remove some rows based on date time stamps. Is there an alternative? Thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried to use 'filter'?

Comment: You can use multiple source transformations with multiple CSVs and Union them together, then Filter out the rows you don't want to keep.

Comment: I post  answer to end this question.If you have  any other doubt,feel free to  ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,use 'union' to migrate your csv files as source.

Then,use 'filter' to filter your data with date time stamps at source.